# Project ContourPlot3D onto 2D slices. It is possible?

Tags: differential-equations, plotting

I've generated a Contourplot3D from a pde[t,x,y,z]. Now, i'm trying to project this contourplot over slices of images that move on the x, y and z axes.

What I want is that when moving the slices a sweep is made through ContourPlot3D and it is projected on the planes of the images in the three axes. Similar to SliceContourPlot3D but specifically on the slices of images.

The following is the code I did to move the slices in the three axes from an image dataset.

```
arc = "C:\\Users\\SKNT\\Documents\\MEGA\\Progra\\Mathematica\\Inputs\\\...
M4-Axi(skull-full)Stanford";
M4 = Import[arc, #] & /@ Import[arc];
(Image[#, ImageSize -> 32]) & /@ M4;

color = Reverse[
ParallelMap[
With[{img = #}, 
  ColorCombine[{Colorize[img, ColorFunction -> "SolarColors"], 
    Binarize[img]}, "RGB"]] &, M4]];

(Image[#, ImageSize -> 32]) & /@ color;

data = Developer`ToPackedArray[Map[ImageData, color]];

With[{vista = {5, 8, 7}},
Manipulate[
Graphics3D[{Opacity[Dynamic[o]], Texture[data], EdgeForm[], Dynamic[{

  With[{pts = 
     Table[{{x, 0, 0}, {x, 1, 0}, {x, 1, 1}, {x, 0, 1}}, {x, 0, 
       xx, step}]},
   Polygon[pts, VertexTextureCoordinates -> pts]],
  With[{pts = 
     Table[{{0, y, 0}, {1, y, 0}, {1, y, 1}, {0, y, 1}}, {y, 0, 
       yy, step}]},
   Polygon[pts, VertexTextureCoordinates -> pts]],

  With[{pts = 
     Table[{{0, 0, z}, {1, 0, z}, {1, 1, z}, {0, 1, z}}, {z, 0, 
       zz, step}]},
   Polygon[pts, VertexTextureCoordinates -> pts]],


  Polygon[{{x, 0, 0}, {x, 1, 0}, {x, 1, 1}, {x, 0, 1}}, 
   VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{x, 0, 0}, {x, 1, 0}, {x, 1, 
      1}, {x, 0, 1}}], 
  Polygon[{{0, y, 0}, {1, y, 0}, {1, y, 1}, {0, y, 1}}, 
   VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, y, 0}, {1, y, 0}, {1, y, 
      1}, {0, y, 1}}], 
  Polygon[{{0, 0, z}, {1, 0, z}, {1, 1, z}, {0, 1, z}}, 
   VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0, z}, {1, 0, z}, {1, 1, 
      z}, {0, 1, z}}]}]},
      Background -> Black, RotationAction -> "Clip", 
  ViewPoint -> vista],
       {{x, 0.5}, 0, 1}, {{y, 0.5}, 0, 1}, {{z, 0.5}, 0, 
  1}, {{o, 0.75, "Opacidad"}, 0, 1}, {{xx, 0, "X"}, .0, 
  1}, {{yy, 0, "Y"}, .0, 1}, {{zz, 0, "Z"}, .0, 
  1}, {{step, 0.05, "Paso"}, .005, 0.09}]]
```

This input code generate the output:

[image: Slices of images]

The contour plot 3D is this

[image]

By the way, the ContourPlot3D evolves over time.

I hope you can help me with some suggestions. I'll be very greatful

P.S. I forgot it!... The dataset of images can be downloaded from: https://graphics.stanford.edu/data/voldata/cthead-8bit.tar.gz

Update 1:

This is a bad attempt to combine SlicesContourPlot3D with slices of head (images). Both slices move independently and the contours of contourplot3D are not projected on the planes of the images or slices of head.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to test without knowing explicitly what goes into `ContourPlot3D`, but here's my take on it.

We can plot with `SliceContourPlot3D` and `"X(Y)(Z)StackedPlanes"` choices that vary with the `Manipulate`. Since I don't know what to plot, I'll use a placeholder expression with a custom `RegionFunction` setting.

```
With[{vista = {5, 8, 7}},
Manipulate[
Show[
Graphics3D[{Opacity[Dynamic[o]], Texture[data], EdgeForm[], Dynamic[{

  With[{pts = 
     Table[{{x, 0, 0}, {x, 1, 0}, {x, 1, 1}, {x, 0, 1}}, {x, 0, 
       xx, step}]},
   Polygon[pts, VertexTextureCoordinates -> pts]],
  With[{pts = 
     Table[{{0, y, 0}, {1, y, 0}, {1, y, 1}, {0, y, 1}}, {y, 0, 
       yy, step}]},
   Polygon[pts, VertexTextureCoordinates -> pts]],

  With[{pts = 
     Table[{{0, 0, z}, {1, 0, z}, {1, 1, z}, {0, 1, z}}, {z, 0, 
       zz, step}]},
   Polygon[pts, VertexTextureCoordinates -> pts]],


  Polygon[{{x, 0, 0}, {x, 1, 0}, {x, 1, 1}, {x, 0, 1}}, 
   VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{x, 0, 0}, {x, 1, 0}, {x, 1, 
      1}, {x, 0, 1}}], 
  Polygon[{{0, y, 0}, {1, y, 0}, {1, y, 1}, {0, y, 1}}, 
   VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, y, 0}, {1, y, 0}, {1, y, 
      1}, {0, y, 1}}], 
  Polygon[{{0, 0, z}, {1, 0, z}, {1, 1, z}, {0, 1, z}}, 
   VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0, z}, {1, 0, z}, {1, 1, 
      z}, {0, 1, z}}]}]},
      Background -> Black, RotationAction -> "Clip", 
  ViewPoint -> vista],
  SliceContourPlot3D[Sin[a] + b^2 - c^3, 
   {{"XStackedPlanes", {x}}, {"YStackedPlanes", {y}}, {"ZStackedPlanes", {z}}}, 
   {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}, {c, 0, 1}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[{a, b, c, f}, 0 < f < .5], 
   Contours -> Subdivide[0, .5, 10], PlotTheme -> "CoolColor", 
   PerformanceGoal -> ControlActive["Speed", "Quality"]]
  ],
       {{x, 0.5}, 0, 1}, {{y, 0.5}, 0, 1}, {{z, 0.5}, 0, 
  1}, {{o, 0.75, "Opacidad"}, 0, 1}, {{xx, 0, "X"}, .0, 
  1}, {{yy, 0, "Y"}, .0, 1}, {{zz, 0, "Z"}, .0, 
  1}, {{step, 0.05, "Paso"}, .005, 0.09}]]
```

[image]